# no response from express :: npm behind OSX proxy setting

Tags: node.js, macos, express, proxy, npm

I've set up osx Proxy with username and password checked the followings:

- auto proxy discovery
- web proxy with ip, port, username, and pass
- same for the secure web proxy

So far these are what've done: on .npmrc file

- proxy http://username:pass@111.111.1.11:port
- https-proxy http://username:pass@111.111.1.11:port
- strict-ssl false

when I request any get from my node and express app, I get these errors 
Status: 503 Service Unavailable

Header == >

- Connection →keep-alive
- Content-Length →3555
- Content-Type →text/html
- Date →Fri, 25 Nov 2016 22:22:05 GMT
- Mime-Version →1.0
- Server    →squid/3.1.9
- X-Squid-Error →ERR_CONNECT_FAIL 101

When I go to any websites it works.
When I go to whatsmyip, it shows my proxy ip 
any https and http websites no issues 
BUT I can't get a single request ever since changing my proxy on my osx.

Help and would you be able to explain what is going on?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: One thing I forgot to disclose is that my proxy ip port is not 8080. could that be the issue?